# Pyramid interprets %2F as reqular forward slash

Tags: pyramid

I'm working with Pylons Pyramid and came accross following issue:
One of my views is expecting a string within GET parameter and I found out this string can contain '/'. On client side I have escaped '/' with '%2F' however Pyramid is still interpreting this as '/'.

So when I type http://127.0.0.1/some%2Fvalue pyramid interprets it as http://127.0.0.1/some/value

Is there a way to make pyramid to interpret such address as http://127.0.0.1/some%2Fvalue?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not Pyramid; you'll need to encode the %-sign properly inside the URL itself.

Comment: Oh, so I need to escape `%` as well? Or should I look to encode `/` different way than I try to do this now?

Comment: I should add that later in my application I would like to see %2F unescaped back to '/'
So if I wanted to escape `%2F` I would get `%252F` which then would appear on the server as `%2F`

Comment: You might be right that this won't work, and my comment was too hasty.